# Nested/recursive groupby count in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with more than 2 million rows, that looks like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+
|   PartitionKey    |    RowKey    |  Type  |            Path            |    Name     |
+-------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+
| /                 | /People      | Folder | /People                    | People      |
| /People           | /index1.xlsx | File   | /People/index1.xlsx        | index1.xlsx |
| /People           | /index2.xlsx | File   | /People/index2.xlsx        | index2.xlsx |
| /People           | /index3.xlsx | File   | /People/index3.xlsx        | index3.xlsx |
| /People           | /Employees   | Folder | /People/Employees          | Employees   |
| /People/Employees | /cv1.pdf     | File   | /People/Employees/cv1.pdf  | cv1.pdf     |
| /People/Employees | /cv2.pdf     | File   | /People/Employees/cv2.pdf  | cv2.pdf     |
| /People/Employees | /cv3.pdf     | File   | /People/Employees/cv3.pdf  | cv3.pdf     |
| /                 | /Buildings   | Folder | /Buildings                 | Buildings   |
| /Buildings        | /index1.xlsx | File   | /Buildings/index1.xlsx     | index1.xlsx |
| /Buildings        | /index2.xlsx | File   | /Buildings/index2.xlsx     | index2.xlsx |
| /Buildings        | /index3.xlsx | File   | /Buildings/index3.xlsx     | index3.xlsx |
| /Buildings        | /Rooms       | Folder | /Buildings/Rooms           | Rooms       |
| /Buildings/Rooms  | /room1.pdf   | File   | /Buildings/Rooms/room1.pdf | room1.pdf   |
| /Buildings/Rooms  | /room2.pdf   | File   | /Buildings/Rooms/room2.pdf | room2.pdf   |
| /Buildings/Rooms  | /room3.pdf   | File   | /Buildings/Rooms/room3.pdf | room3.pdf   |
+-------------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------+-------------+
```

I want to add two new columns: `DirectFileCount` and `RecursiveFileCount`.

Those should indicate the number of files within the folder itself, and the number of files within itself and all sub folders recursively, as per the `Path` --> `PartitionKey` relationship from the folders to files.

It should make the `DataFrame` look like this:

```
+-------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|   PartitionKey    |    RowKey    |  Type  |           Path            |    Name     | DirectFileCount | RecursiveFileCount |
+-------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| /                 | /People      | Folder | /People                   | People      |               3 |                  6 |
| /People           | /index1.xlsx | File   | /People/index1.xlsx       | index1.xlsx |               0 |                  0 |
| /People           | /index2.xlsx | File   | /People/index2.xlsx       | index2.xlsx |               0 |                  0 |
| /People           | /index3.xlsx | File   | /People/index3.xlsx       | index3.xlsx |               0 |                  0 |
| /People           | /Employees   | Folder | /People/Employees         | Employees   |               3 |                  3 |
| /People/Employees | /cv1.pdf     | File   | /People/Employees/cv1.pdf | cv1.pdf     |               0 |                  0 |
| /People/Employees | /cv2.pdf     | File   | /People/Employees/cv2.pdf | cv2.pdf     |               0 |                  0 |
| /People/Employees | /cv3.pdf     | File   | /People/Employees/cv3.pdf | cv3.pdf     |               0 |                  0 |
+-------------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I have something for direct count that works:

```
df_count = df.groupby(['.tag', 'PartitionKey']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
df_file_count = df_count[df_count['.tag'] == 'file'].set_index('PartitionKey')

def direct_count(row):
    if row['.tag'] == 'folder':
        try:
            return df_file_count.loc[row['path_lower']].counts
        except:
            pass

    return 0

df['DirectFileCount'] = df.apply(lambda row: direct_count(row), axis=1)
```

The above code takes care of `DirectFileCount` and completes in less than 2 minutes.

**UPDATE 16th Oct. 2019**

I got `RecursiveFileCount` completed, but it took 1h 52mins. Code below:

```
dfc = df[df['Type'] == 'Folder'][['PartitionKey', 'DirectFileCount']].set_index('PartitionKey').groupby('PartitionKey').sum()

def recursive_count(row):
    count = 0

    if row['Type'] == 'Folder':
        count = dfc[dfc.index.str.startswith(row['Path'])]['DirectFileCount'].sum()

    return count

df['RecursiveFileCount'] = df.apply(lambda row: recursive_count(row), axis=1)
```

Got it working now to produce the results I needed. However, it is fairly slow with 2.7m rows so hopefully someone has an idea for improving performance.

Comment: Please explain the logic of your newly created columns in words, instead of just giving us code.

Comment: @Erfan Sure, added now.

Comment: Can you add some more example data where the folder switches from `/People` to another one? So I can test if it works for different folders and not only subfolders.

Comment: @Erfan Added more now, hopefully it is in line with what you needed.

Comment: Yes, this will help.